# Excel formula for EQUAL TO when working with lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to automate some tedious daily work in an excel file. What i want to do is:

Paste a list into column **N**.

Then...

If anything in column **N** is equal to anything in column **D**, change the value of the adjacent cell of column **D** (Column **F**) to "Collected"

**Screenshot details:** *Column D is static, data does not change. Column F contains a list in which "collected" is part of this list. Column N is where i plan to paste the list to compare the data to column D*

[image]

UPDATE:

User Eleshar suggested i try his formula however it doesn't work correctly.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D2:D144,N2) >0, "Collected","Not Scheduled")
```

It does verify that the data in column N matches the data of the column D list however it does not highlight the correct adjacent cell. It just highlights cells starting from F2 onwards

See screenshot: [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/49bd52662b.png)

Comment: =IF(OR(A:A=B:B), "Collected","Not Scheduled")

Comment: just change A:A=B:B to your desirable columns A:A it will select all column A, same thing on B:B

Comment: In col F do a MATCH of the col D value to col N.  A non-error result is "Collected".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, column F is the one where you establish whether the value on the same line in column N is found anywhere in the column D. If so, the formula should be this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(N:N,D2)>0,"Collected","whatever")
```

Copy to F2 and then copy as formula to all cells below.

*COUNTIF* will give you the number of occurrences of a value found in the same row of column D within the column N. If this is larger than 0, the value is "collected".

EDIT: Adjusted the formula for English language version and most importantly for the correct way of searching.

Comment: Excel keeps throwing an error for that formula (is this a formula error)

Comment: Any suggestions Eleshar?

Comment: I corrected your formula however it doesnt work correctly.

Comment: I corrected your formula however it doesnt work correctly.

'=IF(COUNTIF(D2:D144,N2) >0, "Collected","Not Scheduled")'

It does verify that the data in column N matches the data of the column D list however it does not highlight the correct adjacent cell. It just highlights cells starting from F2 onwards

See screenshot: [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/49bd52662b.png)

Comment: Hm, the error might be using semi-column instead of comma, otherwise it should work (I would recommend D:D though because otherwise, you need to adjust for proper row count and use D$2:D$144). I am not sure however, what you mean be "highlighting the correct adjacent cell". Do you mean that cell in column D should also change colour somehow when it is collected? If so, please modify your question.

Comment: Wait, im an idiot. The formula should search D value in N column, not vice versa... Adjusting the answer now.

Comment: I think you mean.. `=IF(COUNTIF(N:N,D2)>0,"Collected","whatever")`

Comment: @p._phidot_ You are right of course!